Neither reducible nor irreducible representation of a cyclic group
In the book "Representations and characters of groups" (Gordon James & Martin Liebeck) there is this exercise:

Let $G = C_{13}$ (cyclic group of order 13), Find a $\mathbb{C}G$-module which is neither reducible nor irreducible.

Is this possible? and if so can you say if my example works?
I know that $C_{13}$ is abelian, so its irreducible $\mathbb{C}$ representations  are all of degree $1$. So if we are looking for a one that is not irreducible then it should be of degree $> 1$.
I start by identifying $ G = \mathbb{Z}/13 \mathbb{Z}$ and I am thinking of the representation $(\mathbb{C}^2, \rho )$ such that:
$$ \rho (n)(x,y) = (x+ \zeta^n y, y) $$
Where $\zeta$ a $13$ root of unity. This gives me a matrix that it is not diagonalizable, so it is not reducible, and not irreducible.

Every representation is either reducible or irreducible, since irreducible literally means "not reducible." There can be representations which are reducible but not decomposable (as a direct sum of subreps), but that doesn't happen in the semisimple world. And all complex representations of finite groups are semisimple, so this exercise seems wrong. You should specify where in the book this exercise is from. Also your example is wrong because it is not a homomorphism.

Looks like it's Exercise 5 from Chapter 5 on pg52 of the 2nd edition. Yeah, it's wrong. My best guess is the author was thinking about the problem of finding a reducible but not decomposable $C_{13}$-rep over the finite field $F=\mathbb{F}_{13}$, but it's not clear to me at that point in the text if the reader is familiar with finite fields or decomposability.

Every representation is determined by the image of the generator, and thus you need a $n\times n$ matrix $A$ for some $n>1$ such that $A^{13}=I$ which is not diagonalizable.

@coiso Thank you, that is what I was telling myself, I am undergraduate and new to the theory (which is in french in my university (Bourbaki terminology)) so I wasn't sure, and yes it is the exercise you mentioned. Thank you for clearing that up.
I see that it becomes an example of the necessity of the hypotheses in Maschke theorem if we take the field of characteristic $13$.

@ThomasAndrews Which is impossible because $X^{13} -1$ splits in $\mathbb{C}$ and is separable. So I can't find a representation that is not irreducible and not decomposable. Thank you.

@coiso I am sorry if I am being stupid, but If we take $V = {0}$ and $\rho: g \longrightarrow 0 $, isn't $(V, \rho)$ such a representation that is neither reducible nor irreducible?

You know what, $\dim V=0$ might technically count as neither reducible nor irreducible. I never thought about that before! Good catch. I guess it's like $1$ being neither prime nor composite.

@coiso Ah ok thank you, the problem was for me: "what is $GL_0 (\mathbb{C})$" it can't be empty because it is a group, so it must contain the identity element that sends everything to $0$.
